# retire [colors] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

A recent question came up using the [`colors`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) tag.  Right now, there are only 10 questions with this tag, and they mostly seem to refer either to [`faces`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faces) or [`font-lock`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-lock).

The `colors` tag seems ripe for retirement given the small number of tagged questions and ambiguous use.  Would people prefer to

1. burninate it entirely,
2. make it a synonym for either `faces` or `font-lock` (and if so, which?), or
3. leave it as is?

Answer (score 4):

- [How to change the mouse pointer colour?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3183/how-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-colour)
  [mouse](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mouse) captures what it's about, plus perhaps [themes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themes). [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) is correct but not really relevant.
- [How do I set the fringe colors to whatever is the background color?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5342/how-do-i-set-the-fringe-colors-to-whatever-is-the-background-color)
  [fringe](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fringe) is what it's about. [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) is marginally relevant.
- [Green lines are invisible in diff output for some files in *shell*](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/green-lines-are-invisible-in-diff-output-for-some-files-in-shell)
  [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) is somewhat relevant (the question is about `git diff --color`) but it's a symptom, not the root cause.
- [Different results using color-theme-select versus color-theme-<theme-name>](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/different-results-using-color-theme-select-versus-color-theme-theme-name)
  [themes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themes) is the most important part, but [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) is relevant too.
- [Are there color pickers for Emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/are-there-color-pickers-for-emacs)
  [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) is what this is all about.
- [How to change helm's highlight color](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/how-to-change-helms-highlight-color)
  [faces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faces) or [text-properties](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-properties) is what the question is fundamentally about. A new user might not know that colors are configured through faces though.
- [Ways to unobtrusively vary text rendering?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7354/ways-to-unobtrusively-vary-text-rendering)
  This is about [text-properties](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-properties) but [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) is pretty relevant too.
- [Show colors in mode-line for minor modes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7863/show-colors-in-mode-line-for-minor-modes)
  This is about [text-properties](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-properties), really, but here again a new user might not know that colors are a particular case of text properties. [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) is correct but not very relevant.
- [Color-code a new generic character combination](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/color-code-a-new-generic-character-combination)
  This is about [font-lock](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-lock), [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) isn't relevant. Again [font-lock](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-lock) isn't obvious for new users.
- [How to make the custom font lock keywords not override the default major mode font lock?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8222/how-to-make-the-custom-font-lock-keywords-not-override-the-default-major-mode-fo)
  Same as the previous question.

Conclusion: 4/10 definite misuse of [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) instead of [tags:text-properties], [tags:faces] or [tags:font-lock]. 4/10 where [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) is marginal. 2/10 where [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors) is important, including one where it's legitimately the sole tag.

I don't think we can get rid of [colors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colors), though we should discourage its use when the question is really about [text-properties](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-properties), [faces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faces), [font-lock](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-lock) or [themes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themes).

I propose to keep the tag, and write a tag wiki that explains when to use other tags instead. (I'm putting it on my to-do list; if someone wants to do it, they're welcome.) I think we can live with that, and retag mistagged questions as they come in. Let's see how it goes, if we're overwhelmed by misuse we can consider retagging legitimate uses to [color-something](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-something) with a name that discourages misuse.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but disagree with the conclusions you draw from your conclusion. :-) a tag with 4 definite misuses and 2 legitimate uses is asking to be slaughtered.

Comment: @Malabarba What tag would you use for the questions that are actually about colors then?

Comment: the only one that's non trivial to tag is the color picker. I can't think of any tag that really fits it well, so I would just compromise and use `faces` (even though it's not a good tag here). Generally I would be fine with letting a tag exist because there's one question that really needs it. But this tag in particular is doing more harm than good. It's fragmenting questions about all these other tags, and mixing them up in one meaningless tag.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, synonym would be better as everyone might not be familiar with the emacs terms like `faces` and `font-lock`.

Comment: Good point.  Preferences between the two?

Comment: I like `font-lock` as it means *locking* color/size/shape/etc properties to a *font* to give that text some special meaning.

Comment: Synonym to what? [I looked at the questions](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/a/262) and [tag:colors] could be about [tag:themes], [tag:text-properties], [tag:faces], [tag:font-lock]… There isn't a clear choice between these different meanings, so a synonym is not appropriate.

Comment: @kaushalmodi we ought to make syntax coloring a synonym of font locking. That way people typing "color" would be able to find font locking. However, `colors`, by itself, is much closer to faces than to font locking IMO.

Answer (score 1):

There is zero reason to remove tag `colors`. There is every reason to write a tag wiki that specifies what the tag involves.

More precisely, I would propose changing the tag from `colors` to **`color`**.  The confusions that some of you are worried about will, I think, be reduced just by making this name change.

It is questions about **color** (color models, how Emacs Lisp manipulates colors, etc.) that should be captured by the tag, and not questions about faces, themes, font-lock or other highlighting, etc. (they have their own tags).  IOW, the tag has a raison d'etre, and that is questions & information that are specifically about *color* (not colors).

And no, it is ***not*** the case that (as Malabarba said) "*A color, in elisp, is nothing but a face attribute.*"  Faces might be where Emacs Lisp uses color, but questions about color do not necessarily reduce to questions about faces.

There is plenty in Emacs that is about color and not just about faces, themes, font-locking, etc. And even some posts that might have to do primarily with faces or themes etc. can also involve specific information about color.

It is not because some questions about font-locking or whatever do ***NOT*** involve dealing with color issues specifically that there are not other questions that do deal with color issues (as well as with faces or whatever).

It is not an accident that Emacs has functions for manipulating and displaying color names and color RGB or HSV components.

The proposal to replace (merge) tag `colors` with `faces` or any of the other tags discussed is misguided, IMO. Rename it to **`color`**, and clarify to users what the tag is for. The tag wiki can specifically mention other tags such as `faces` and when to use them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, merge it into [faces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faces) and make it a synonym. Other tags like font-lock or text properties might be worth adding to some of these questions, but they have more distinct meanings and that's a case by case thing. The tag color as a whole should be a synonym of faces.

---

Out of all current uses, the only one where color suits better than faces is: [Are there color pickers for Emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/are-there-color-pickers-for-emacs) . And even here [faces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faces) would be an acceptable tag (though we can manually find a more appropriate one for this).

As a second point, what would be the purpose of a color tag? A color, in elisp, is nothing but a face attribute. Having a color tag is like having a `weight` tag or an `underline` tag. It's too small to warrant a tag (as exemplified by the total of 1 use so far where it works better than [faces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faces)).

Comment: No, merging into [tag:faces] is not sensible. Of the 10 questions currently tagged [tag:colors], only one is about faces. Others are about properties, themes, font lock, …

Comment: @Gilles except for the mouse pointer and the color picker questions, every single mention of "color" in those questions is a reference to the `color` property of faces, so I disagree with your statement. Of the 10 questions, 8 of them can easily be tagged [tag:faces]. Of course, most of them can *also* be given other tags (and they should, that's what I said on the first paragraph).

Comment: No, [tag:faces] wouldn't make sense on http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7354/ways-to-unobtrusively-vary-text-rendering for example, and it's as irrelevant as [tag:colors] for http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/color-code-a-new-generic-character-combination and its sibling. [tag:text-properties] is less wrong but still too different to be a synonym.

Comment: @Gilles I disagree. I think faces is a great tag for the first question and a marginal tag for the second.